# Why am I getting compilation error with this .Net web app using IIS express?

Tags: .net, iis

I have tried every solution that is on google and stack overflow, but none of the solutions worked for me.

I have tried to recycle the app pool that didn't work. 
I made sure that app pool is not set to Local System. 
I recompiled the project and redeployed to another machine all the required project files, but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

> Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code
>   -2146232576.

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

> c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>C:\WINDOWS\RFD\bin\roslyn\csc.exe
>   /t:library /utf8output /nostdlib+
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\8db95c56\5c7800b6_ac0dd301\System.Web.Mvc.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\a733e2a0\9492dfb4_ac0dd301\Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\12f812c4\fd43cab5_ac0dd301\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\003db46e\846fdcb5_ac0dd301\System.Web.Helpers.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\3a93d99f\7ed20fb5_ac0dd301\Microsoft.AI.Web.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\9b9e78d3\55ce77b5_ac0dd301\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\fa96fe3b\b4dd41b4_ac0dd301\Antlr3.Runtime.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\19ced847\ab4cefb4_ac0dd301\Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\d4fbae34\ae821ab5_ac0dd301\Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\9378c45f\326bacb4_ac0dd301\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\1b9d17dc\8b4507b5_ac0dd301\Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\fbbaaf88\975c93b4_ac0dd301\EntityFramework.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\c9ca619b\a87a84b5_ac0dd301\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\0364b14c\476dd3b5_ac0dd301\System.Spatial.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\f6e964d0\02f596b5_ac0dd301\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\86ecafb4\684824b5_ac0dd301\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\bce9306f\297037b6_ac0dd301\WebActivatorEx.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\00eea54e\6ae32fb5_ac0dd301\Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\32ac47d2\a7f226b6_ac0dd301\System.Web.WebPages.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\1d286071\4faba8b5_ac0dd301\POSSytem.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\716bcf63\8233f1b5_ac0dd301\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\8aa0c69a\c3b035b5_ac0dd301\Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\5aadd0c4\17650ab6_ac0dd301\System.Web.Optimization.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\e2e6a604\4c31e8b5_ac0dd301\System.Web.Http.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\39319399\86ef3db5_ac0dd301\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\83ef7f71\0e387eb5_ac0dd301\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\5ee2f2f1\aa5cfbb4_ac0dd301\Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\dc652fe2\32a5a1b5_ac0dd301\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\6280144e\eb2db7b5_ac0dd301\Swashbuckle.Core.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\8d723bb8\dd3e66b5_ac0dd301\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\b0f1f157\3e57c0b5_ac0dd301\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\6fb480f6\4d1515b6_ac0dd301\System.Web.Razor.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\a0c133a6\6e421cb6_ac0dd301\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\286bd523\62344db5_ac0dd301\Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\822a0615\e4c931b6_ac0dd301\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\assembly\dl3\eb7a0df3\cbf34eb6_ac0dd301\WebGrease.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll"
>   /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\App_global.asax.hqvyndbz.dll"
>   /debug- /optimize+ /warnaserror- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618
>   /langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701 
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\App_global.asax.hqvyndbz.0.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\possytem\084bee03\3d5d36d0\App_global.asax.hqvyndbz.1.cs"

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.36366

Comment: Think you need to be isolating the bit of code causing that and submitting it to Microsoft, especially as you say it does the same on another machine

Comment: I've run into similar issues before and in almost every case, it was due to a bad temp file. I'd suggest starting with cleaning out the ASP.NET temp files and then trying again. In the stack trace you provided, your temp directory is `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\possytem`.

Comment: It turned out to be those temp files. To solve this problem I copied temp files from another computer where it was working and pasted here. It started working. This is really odd.

Answer (score 1):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54894542/11121833) solution. It should solve your issue. I encountered this issue and changing the bitness to x64 solved in my case, as my machine is a 64 bit. If you are using VS 2017, this is very handy and easy to do.